# Nested Fragments lose calls to onCreateOptionsMenu after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, screen-orientation, oncreateoptionsmenu

I implemented an Activity (`A`) that displays only one fragment (`PF`) with `getSupportFragmentManager()`.
Fragment (`PF`) has one ViewPager to display 2 Fragments (`F1` and `F2`).
ViewPager uses `FragmentPagerAdapter` with `getChildFragmentManager()`.

[Relative Code](https://github.com/marsucsb/nested-fragments) (ViewPagerActivity)

`PF` has `setRetainInstance(true)` and I added `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` to PF, F1 and F2 because they have personalize optionmenus.

Everything works fine. When I swype between `F1` and `F2` actionbar changes showing optionmenu 1 or optionmenu 2, but when screen rotation happens optionmenus in fragments 1 and 2 are no longer called after swype.

Comment: I think you are facing this issue https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/828

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `setRetainInstance(true)` to F1 and F2 too. Since fragments can have their own option menus you have to tell android that it should retain your child fragments too and not just the parent fragment.

Comment: is this issue you are talking about https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/828??

Comment: Not quite sure what you are talking about. I posted this in 2013, 4 years ago. ;)